# Python or Django library to convert html to an image or pdf

Tags: python, django, image-processing, pdf-generation

So I have two main issues:

1. Finding a library that can convert an html file to an image and pdf (two separate libraries works too)
2. Perform the conversion without exposing the html template in a URL

What I've tried so far:

- I tried using imgkit but from my research, it's incompatible with my docker image:
  (`python:3.7.11-alpine3.13`). This was the error I was getting:
  `OSError: wkhtmltoimage exited with non-zero code -11. error: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root`
- I tried using django's `render_to_string`, to generate a string which can be saved as an html file containing the rendered context data. However, `for` iterations were not rendered in the string output of `render_to_string`
- Currently the only way for me to generate a valid html page with all the passed context data is by using `render`. However this implementation would not work because I can only access the html body via a URL, which in my case is a no-no for security resasons.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html